# Необходимо произвести импорт списка машин из csv файла в базу данных mongodb, используя python

Tags: python, парсер, mongodb, csv

Есть csv файл типа:
-Полное название машины -Доступные цвета -мощность двигателя 
-audi a8L               -black           -...

31 машина. Необходимо всю информацию по ним перебросить в бд mongo;
На просторах гугла наткнулся на данный код:

```
import os
import pandas
import pymongo
import json

def import_content(filepath):
    Mngclient = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    mngdb = mngclient[имя бд]
    collection_name = 'имя коллекции'
    Dbcm = mngdb[collection_name]
    cdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_res = os.path.join(cdir, filepath)

    data = pd.read_csv(file_res)
    Data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orien='records'))
    dbcm.remove()
    dbcm.insert(data_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath ='csv файл'
    import_content(filepath)
```

вроде как всё легко, но никак не могу дать ладу. буду рад помощи. Код выдаёт одну ошибку. Подскажите что можно в него добавить или исправитт, заранее спасибоо.

Traceback:
line 21- import_content(filepath) и line 14- data=pd.read_csv(file_res)

Comment: приведите в вопросе полный `error traceback`

Comment: Код не синтаксически не корректный. После строки `if __name__ == '__main__':` должен быть отступ.

Comment: Приведите ПОЛНЫЙ error traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка явно говорит, что в последней строчке вашего кода вы используете переменную `filepath`, которой не существует.

В том, коде, который вы привели в вопросе переменная очевидно существует. Следовательно, тот код, который реально запускаете вы, чем-то отличается от того, который вы привели в вопросе. Ищете отличия.

Почти наверняка проблема в предпоследней строке. По какой-то причине в вашем реальном коде в ней не создаётся переменная `filepath`. Тщательно проверьте эту строку на опечатки. Лучше - просто сотрите её и напишите заново.

UPD: Кстати, я посмотрел по истории изменений вопроса - до этого у вас там были ВООБЩЕ другие ошибки. Если вы меняете код и приводите уже новые ошибки, то это может запутывать людей, которые пытаются вам помочь.

Comment: Полный трэйсбэк содержит ещё и строчку с описанием ошибки. Она самая последняя и обычно она начинается со слова, которое содержит в себе `Error` (хотя не обязательно). Без этой строчки я не могу узнать, что за ошибка, вижу только, в какой она строчке. По какой-то причине не читается csv-файл. По какой именно - смогу сказать, когда приведёте строчку с самой ошибкой.